# Found a malformed 'form' tag helper. Tag helpers must have a start and end tag or be self closing

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, forms

So i'm getting this error on my mvc project while working on my form.
The error indicates that I haven't closed the form tag properly.
However, as you'll see below, I have closed it properly.

```
<form method="post">

  //form content below

</form>
```

I have added taghelpers in my `ViewImports.cshtml` file as you can see below.

```
@using ServiceWebsite
@using ServiceWebsite.Models
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing the same problem but I have solve it with the following :

- Either using pure html form
- Or inject Helper tags into the form like so

```html
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Main", FormMethod.Post))
{
<form>
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    @if (@ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
        <div style="border: 1px solid red">
            @ViewBag.Message
        </div>
    }
    <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label">@Html.LabelFor(UserBindingModel => UserBindingModel.UserName) </label>
        
    </div>
    
}
```

Save it and it will disappear.
I used this [website](https://learningprogramming.net/net/asp-net-core-razor-pages/login-form-with-session-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages/) as a reference.

Another example of functional form:

```html
@model UserBindingModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Login";
}

<form asp-action="Login">

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label asp-for="UserName" class="form-label"></label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" asp-for="UserName">
    </div>

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label asp-for="Password" class="form-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="Password" class="form-control">
    </div>


</form>
```

Answer (score 9):

May you have an unclosed quotation.

The same problem happened to me because I haven't closed " in readonly="readonly

```
 <form class="form customized-bg-color" asp-action="Create" method="post">
       <div class="col-lg-3  ">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control " id="Total" readonly="readonly />
                </div>        
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used a similar approach to debug as @Wil Campbell.

In my case, it was a mistake in a script definition.  I had mistakenly changed a link that was going to be in a head (which uses href to load stylesheets) to a script (which uses src to load script files like javascript), but I forgot to change href to script when I did so.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34679203)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check the `href` attribute of Your stylesheets and images.

Answer (score 0):

I also hit this "error", VS 2022 .Net 6 project, also with a well-formed, uh, form :)  I removed the form tag & closing tag, rebuilt the project, then added them back in.  Built just fine, issue did not reoccur. Depending on what you are trying to to, I'd try that before doing any major code changes...

Answer (score 0):

the Form tag and its closing SHOULD be IN its container if it has one, I had the same problem.
your form tag should Not be Like this

```html
<div>
<form>
</div>
</form>
```

Correct:

```html
<div>
  <form>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing " somewhere in your form tag

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Check the quotes in your code.

If you missed quote/double quotes this is one of the reason why you are getting this error.

In my case this is a simple unnecesary quote was in the html tag:

```
  <div id="relatedCellExperiments" ">
  </div>
```